# Problem in ssh port forwarding on Mac

Tags: unix, ssh, portforwarding

I've just started playing with ssh on Mac. I want to setup ssh port forwarding.
I tried the following command:

```
ssh -L 10090:192.168.1.105:3892 -l svnac@192.168.1.83
```

On executing this command, the usage of ssh command is displayed on the terminal. Does this mean I have done something wrong? What am I missing over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a `-l` where you don't need it. Try this:

```
ssh -L 10090:192.168.1.105:3892 svnac@192.168.1.83
```